# Combox first row not selectable

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

How to make first row of combobox not-selectable? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox?view=winrt-19041)

Answer (score 1):

> Combox first row not selectable

You could detect `DropDownOpened` event and find the fist item with `ContainerFromIndex` then disable it like the following. Because Combobox dropdown is lazy load, so we need add the task delay in `DropDownOpened` event.

```
private async void MyCb_DropDownOpened(object sender, object e)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    var item = MyCb.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ComboBoxItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.IsEnabled = false;
    }  
}
```