# uwp combobox ContainerfromIndex(0) always returns null

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, combobox, frameworks

I want to pick the first item of combobox when there is no item selected on it, but it's not working with ContainerFromIndex(0) or ContainerFromItem.

I am not sure why it won't work like this because the index method works fine if an item is selected on the combobox, then why won't it work when item isn't selected because items are still there. I can easily get the first item from the item list in code even. Basically I want the first "ComboBoxItem".

```
  if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            //var allItems = comboBox.Items.ToList();
            //var cccc = comboBox.Items.Count;
            //var firstItem = allItems.First();
            var ci = comboBox.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ComboBoxItem;
            if (ci != null)
            {
                ci.StartBringIntoView();
            }
        }
```

### Update

I also tried following code with **Task.Delay(100)** bcz the items are supposed to be lazy loaded, but still getting ci as null, weird thing is comboBox.Items shows all items, and comboBox.ItemSource shows all the count for the items, but **ContainerFromItem** still returns null.

```
  await Task.Delay(100);
  var comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
  if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
  {                
       var ci = comboBox.Items[0];
       var cc = comboBox.ContainerFromItem(ci) as ComboBoxItem;
       if (cc != null)
       {
            cc.StartBringIntoView();
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> uwp combobox ContainerfromIndex(0) always returns null

Please check Combobox style, the listview part was placed in the popup control, it means that the listview will be lazy load. if you don't open the dropdown. the listview part will not render. you could pick one item then call ContainerFromIndex method to verify this. If you want give it the default select item for `Combobox` please give `SelectedIndex` value like the following.

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="CBX"
    Width="200"
    Header="Colors"
    PlaceholderText="Pick a color"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    SelectionChanged="ColorComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <x:String>Blue</x:String>
    <x:String>Green</x:String>
    <x:String>Red</x:String>
    <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: the goal was to open the dropdown and scroll it to top item when no item was selected and scroll it to selected item when an item was selected, the code I have in my question actually executes inside the "dropdown_opened" method and I always get the item when an item is already selected only null when selectedIndex = -1. But in any case I found a work around by putting a behavior on scrollviewer in the style and scrolling to top on loaded event. Thanks anyways.

Comment: yep, and you could also add task delay in the dropdown_opened event please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62534852/7254781)

Comment: unfortunately my own work around is also very inconsistent and does not work always.

Comment: And have you tried add task delay  before getting item like this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62534852/7254781).

Comment: yes I tried the Task.Delay() it still doesnt work.,

Comment: please see the Update part on my question