# Populating ComboBox with DeviceWatcher in Universal Windows Platform C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp

I've took the sample from Microsoft UWP samples library (CameraFrames app) and adopting it to my needs. When starting the application populates ComboBox with the available devices through Devicewatcher class (see the code below).

My special need is to select a particular device in the combobox (by means of GroupComboBox.SelectedIndex property) before the page is shown to the user first time. By the problem is I cant figure out when (on which event) I can do it. I've tried a few events (Page.Loaded, Page.OnNavigatedTo, Combobox.Loaded, Devicewatcher.EnumerationCompleted and others) but the combobox is empty in all these events ao I'm not able to manipulate with the combobox data (but when the page is shown the combobox is populated).

I've found some info in Microsoft sites that it can be multithreading issue but I was not able to understand what to do with it.

THE CODE

In the page constructor:

```
_groupCollection = new SourceGroupCollection(this.Dispatcher);
GroupComboBox.ItemsSource = _groupCollection.FrameSourceGroups;
```

And the class itself

```
public class SourceGroupCollection : IDisposable
{
    private CoreDispatcher _dispatcher;
    private DeviceWatcher _watcher;
    private ObservableCollection<FrameSourceGroupModel> _sourceCollection;

    public SourceGroupCollection(CoreDispatcher uiDispatcher)
    {
        _dispatcher = uiDispatcher;
        _sourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<FrameSourceGroupModel>();

        // Only listen to devices with type of MediaFrameSourceGroup
        var deviceSelector = MediaFrameSourceGroup.GetDeviceSelector();
        _watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(deviceSelector);
        _watcher.Added += Watcher_Added;
        _watcher.Removed += Watcher_Removed;
        _watcher.Updated += Watcher_Updated;
        _watcher.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _watcher.Stop();
        _watcher.Updated -= Watcher_Updated;
        _watcher.Removed -= Watcher_Removed;
        _watcher.Added -= Watcher_Added;
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<FrameSourceGroupModel> FrameSourceGroups
    {
        get { return _sourceCollection; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates a device when a change occurs.
    /// </summary>
    private async void Watcher_Updated(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
    {
        await RemoveDevice(args.Id);
        await AddDeviceAsync(args.Id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a device from the collection when one disconnected.
    /// </summary>
    private async void Watcher_Removed(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
    {
        await RemoveDevice(args.Id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a device to the collection when one connected.
    /// </summary>
    private async void Watcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
    {
        await AddDeviceAsync(args.Id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a SourceGroup with given Id to the collection.
    /// </summary>
    private async Task AddDeviceAsync(string id)
    {
        var group = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FromIdAsync(id);
        if (group != null)
        {
            await _dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    _sourceCollection.Add(new FrameSourceGroupModel(group));
                });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a SourceGroup with given id from the collection if it exists
    /// </summary>
    private async Task RemoveDevice(string id)
    {
        await _dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                var existing = _sourceCollection.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
                if (existing != null)
                {
                    _sourceCollection.Remove(existing);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My special need is to select a particular device in the combobox (by means of GroupComboBox.SelectedIndex property) before the page is shown

Please check Combobox style, the listview part was placed in the popup control, it means that the listview will lazy load. if you don't open the dropdown. the listview part will not render. so you can't get  ComboBoxItem like this   `comboBox.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ComboBoxItem`; and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089301/uwp-combobox-containerfromindex0-always-returns-null/65090442#65090442) is similar case.

For your scenario, you could set `SelectedIndex` in the xaml to specific index item. And if you want to display the specific item

```
var list = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
TestBox.ItemsSource = list;
TestBox.SelectedItem = list.Where(p => p == "3").ToArray()[0];
```

And please note above need to be call in the [UI thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-20348).

**Update**
please get Count property in the UI thread like the following.

```
private async void _watcher_EnumerationCompleted(DeviceWatcher sender, object args)
{
    await _dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        var count = _sourceCollection.Count;
    });
   
}
```

Comment: I need to clarify the following… Before selecting the item I need to learn which item to select so I need to read the data in the combobox before. If the combobox is not populated with the data until it’s opened so how I can define which item to select?

Comment: Your itemsSource get value before the dropdown open, you could check the itemsSource to find the which you want select.

Comment: But when (which event)I I cant check it? As I wrote above there is no any data in the combobox in Page_Loaded and other events

Comment: For getting the complete device list, the better place is `EnumerationCompleted` event.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it as well } private void Watcher_EnumerationCompleted(DeviceWatcher sender, Object args) { var c = _sourceCollection.Count; _isEnumerationCompleted = true; } No data in _sourceCollection

Comment: is there available camera device in your system?

Comment: Of course, There are three video capture devices. And all of them are shown in the ComboBox when the page is shown and I open the list in the combobox

Comment: Please refer above update and get the device in the ui thread by dispatcher .

Comment: I've investigated  "RunTaskAsync extension method" but not able to understand how to implement it into my code. Will you be so kind to help me with it?

Comment: I've modified EnumerationCompleted event as you suggested. Count is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the type of the `FrameSourceGroups` property of the `SourceGroupCollection` class to `ObservableCollection<FrameSourceGroupModel>`, you could handle its `CollectionChanged` to determine when an item has been added.

You can then handle the event and set the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`, e.g.:

```
_groupCollection = new SourceGroupCollection(this.Dispatcher);
GroupComboBox.ItemsSource = _groupCollection.FrameSourceGroups;
_groupCollection.FrameSourceGroups.CollectionChanged += (ss, ee) =>
{
    if (obs.Count > 0)
    {
        //select the first item...
        GroupComboBox.SelectedItem = _groupCollection.FrameSourceGroups[0];
    }
};
```